# Getting different file permission when running in Azure Custom Script extension and in AWS Userdata -Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, azure, file-permissions, user-data

I am running same script in Azure linux (using custom script extension) and AWS Linux box (using user data), but when the script finishes I can see the same file created in both servers have different file permissions.

Update : it is resolved now.
I finally found the answer.
It was selinux which was enforced on the linux. Disabling it solved my all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, you can use Azure custom script extension to create files, Azure will use `root` account to create files.

Use custom script extension to create `file1`, you can find file1 in this `/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.2/download/0`, like this:

```
root@jasonvm:/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.2/download/0# pwd
/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.2/download/0
root@jasonvm:/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.2/download/0# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 21 01:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 21 01:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 21 01:50 errout
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 21 01:50 file1
---x------ 1 root root   11 Feb 21 01:50 script.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 21 01:50 stdout
```

According to the output, Azure use `root` account to create files, so the permission same as use `root` account to create files, permission is `644`.

I am not good at AWS, you can use `ls -al` to check in AWS.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**

Please check `umask` in Azure Linux VM and AWS Linux VM.

Azure Linux VM use default value **0022** of `umask`, so the permission of new file is 644 and new directory is `755`.

[image]

```
[root@jason]# umask
0022
```

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I already tried what you have mentioned in the answer but that didn't solve my problem.  Umask in case of Azure and AWS linux is same for root user.
The problem I am facing is with the file that are getting created via chef-client run. For example a recipe in chef client is copying a file from S3 or some storage and pasting to local system then by default permission on the file I am getting is 600.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because that is useful information which one needs to check first for troubleshooting this kind of issues.